# .htaccess redirecting proper syntax

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want a redirect, using my .htaccess file. I did this a few months back, it was 401 (maybe 301) redirection. I basically want my website to go to /userpage.html if someone accidentally types it /userpage (no .html). I remember being able to do this pretty easily with a redirect in the .htaccess file, but for the life of me I cannot remember the phrasing. I think it was redirect 401, but it does not seem to be working. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it!! I am hung up on this problem, and I know it's a pretty simple and quick fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

on top of your .htaccess to allow **extension-less access** to you file.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^dir/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Code-only answers are frowned on.